# how to map multiple filebeat inputs to logstash configuration in official helm chart?

Tags: logstash, kubernetes-helm, filebeat

I used following pipline in my installioan of logstash on centos machines.
how to map the following pipleline to official helm chart for logstash?

```
     -pipeline.id: beats-server
   config.string: |
    input { beats { port => 5044 ssl => true ssl_key => '/usr/share/logstash/config/certs/logstash-node-pkcs8-key/logstash.pkcs8.key' ssl_certificate => '/usr/share/logstash/config/certs/logstash-node-crt/logstash.crt'}}
    output {
        if [source] == 'filebeat1' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat1 }
        } else if [source] == 'filebeat2' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat2 }
        } else if [source] == 'filebeat3' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat3 }
        } else if [source] == 'filebeat4' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat4 }
        } else if [source] == 'filebeat6' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat6 }
        } else if [source] == 'filebeat5' {
          pipeline { send_to => filebeat5 }
        }
    }
 -pipeline.id: filebeat1-processing
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat1.conf"

 -pipeline.id: filebeat2-processing
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat2.conf"

 -pipeline.id: filebeat3-processing
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat3.conf"

 -pipeline.id: filebeat4-processing
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat4.conf"

 -pipeline.id: filebeat5-processing
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/filebeat5.conf"
```